# How to create a new Record (accounts) on behalf of another user using Dynamics connector

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, azure-logic-apps

I am working on a logic app in Azure that uses the Microsoft Dynamics connector to create a new record; In my case a new account record in accounts.

The sequence is:

1. Add a new action
2. Choose Dynamics connector
3. Pick the "Create new record" action
4. Choose the Organisation Name
5. Choose Entitiy "Accounts"
6. Fill in the mandatory fields like Account Name, Address, Main Phone, etc.
   Done

When I run the LG the account is created just fine, but for my user. However I want the accounts to created for the respective Sales Reps.

So, I added Fields `_ownerid_type` and `_ownerid_value` but that does not make a difference. Is there any other way how to hand over a user id, GUID, or so to make the new record be owner by a distinct user?

Here is my request in code view:

```
"Create_a_new_Account": {
    "inputs": {
        "body": {
            "_ownerid_type": "systemusers",
            "_ownerid_value": "91a58fc6-1ab8-e911-a98a-000d3a276633",
            "address1_city": "Metropolis",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, This is not possible, Reason been There is no provision running Logic Apps as  PreOperation and we can set owner only during pre operation phase.

You will have to assign the record to user after record is created.

But if someone has more experience and has tried this then I can be wrong, But with my knowledge I would say it is not possible to set owner when creating record.

Comment: Ok. Let's assume for the moment you are right. Then would I be able to add a second action (update a record) after creation and change the owner then?

Comment: Yes that should be the way.

Comment: Perfect, I can confirm this works. Use update a record action after create a record to update the owner of the account, contact, lead, etc.